# mysqli_query not recognizing database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've already asked a question on this code I'm working on, just not about the same problem. Either way sorry for the repost!

So I'm having trouble with the code, as follows:

```
<?php
// Create connection

$host = "localhost";
$username="tudor";
$password="passw0rd";

$con=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);
if(! $con )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully<br />';


$db_1 = mysqli_select_db( $con, 'db_1' );
if (! $db_1) {
die('Could not select database: ' . mysqli_error());
}
else {
echo "Database successfully selected<br />===============================<br />";
}

//===================================



$a = 1;
$b = 2234;

$table = "CREATE TABLE info (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, city CHAR(40), country CHAR(40))";
 if (! $table) {
die('Could not create table ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
else {
echo "Table created<br />";
}

$insert = "INSERT INTO info (city, country) VALUES ($a, $b)";
 if (! $insert) {
die('Could not insert ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
else {
echo "Inserted<br />";
}

$select = "SELECT * FROM info";  


$result = mysqli_query ($con, $insert);
 if (! $result) {
die('Result not working ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
else {
echo "Result working<br />";
}

echo "result: ".$result['city']. " ";


mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

This outputs (blockquote doesn't display page breaks):

> Connected successfully Database successfully selected
>   =============================== Table created Inserted Result not working Table 'db_1.info' doesn't exist

What does it mean by "Table 'db.info'" not existing? It clearly says that my info table was created...
What I tried doing is inverting the variables in the $result query: $result = mysqli_query ($insert, $con);, because I had seen that syntax in a book. However all it gave was the following message in the output:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given
>   in C:\wamp...

Thoughts anyone? Thanks in advance!

Edit: really appreciate the help everyone, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok. Here is your code.

```
if(! $con )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully<br />';
if (!$con) {trigger_error("Could not connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error()); }   
else { echo "Database successfully connected<br />===============================<br />"; }
$a = 1;
$b = 2234;
$table = mysqli_query($con,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info (`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`city` CHAR(40), 
`country` CHAR(40), PRIMARY KEY  (`id`) )ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");
  if (!$table) {
die('Could not create table ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
else {
echo "Table created<br />";
}
$insert = mysqli_query ($con,"INSERT INTO info (city, country) VALUES ('$a', '$b')");
 if (!$insert) {
die('Could not insert ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
else {
echo "Inserted<br />";
}
$select =  mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT * FROM info");  
$res=mysqli_fetch_array($select);
 if (! $res) {
die('Result not working ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
else {
echo "Result working<br />";
}

echo "result: ".$res['city']. " ";
echo "result: ".$res['country']. " ";
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: 1) You forgot to add mysqli_query on CREATE TABLE --2) this connection way is faster--3) also forgot to set PRIMARY KEY  (`id`) on CREATE TABLE

Comment: Amazing! Works like a charm, thanks so much! I saw two changes: the details added in the table creation part, and a change from ($con, $insert) to ($con, $result). Although the latter was a problem, I think it was what you changed in the table syntax that made the difference in the table error. Can you explain why this made it work?

Edit: sorry I just saw your comment. Why is this connection faster? And does there always have to be a query for the table creation?

Comment: NO! Now!!! it is working! There was some more mistakes in the insert query. Just edited it. Please copy and review the mistakes of the second half

Comment: @Nik you are still missing a `mysqli_query()` on `$insert` in your suggested code.

Comment: fewer code I meant. Also take care of VALUES ('$a', '$b') needed apostrophes AND didn't have any mysqli_fetch_array while reading the db. Do not forget that INSERT AND UPDATE needs just the mysqli_array, though SELECT needs also the mysqli_fetch_array to fetch the data..

Comment: @Nik it was working fine, except the echo at the end, but I'm still working on that. I don't see a difference with or without the insert query?

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing a `mysqli_query()` on `$table` before your `mysqli_query()` on `$insert`, and you are not doing a `mysqli_query()` on `$select`

```
$table = "CREATE TABLE info (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, city CHAR(40), country CHAR(40))";
 if (! $table)

$insert = "INSERT INTO info (city, country) VALUES ($a, $b)";
 if (! $insert) {

$select = "SELECT * FROM info";  

$result = mysqli_query ($con, $insert);
if (! $result)
```

try adding the `mysqli_query()` -

```
$table_sql = "CREATE TABLE `info` (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `city` CHAR(40), `country` CHAR(40), PRIMARY KEY (`id`))";
$table = mysqli_query ($con, $table_sql);
 if (! $table) {
die('Could not create table ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
else {
echo "Table created<br />";
}

$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO `info` (`city`, `country`) VALUES ('$a', '$b')";
$insert = mysqli_query ($con, $insert_sql);
 if (! $insert) {
die('Could not insert ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
else {
echo "Inserted<br />";
}

$select = "SELECT * FROM `info`";  

$result = mysqli_query ($con, $select);
 if (! $result) {
die('Result not working ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
else {
echo "Result working<br />";
}
```

**Edit**
Also, this line will fail -

```
echo "result: ".$result['city']. " ";
```

as you have to fetch the array from the query using [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

```
$results = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo "result: ".$results['city']. " ";
```

Comment: I'm talking about this query at the end of the code: 
$result = mysqli_query ($con, $insert);

Comment: See my updated answer. You have to do a `mysqli_query()` on `$table`, and `$insert`, before you can do it on `$select`. This line `$result = mysqli_query ($con, $insert);` fails because you are trying to insert `$insert`, when the `$table` was never created. You are also not actually doing your `$select` in that query as you are using `$insert` instead of `$select`.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks a lot for the tips. However, now that I add the changes you showed me, the table can't be created. It gives the following error message: "Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

Comment: In order for a column to have `AUTO_INCREMENT`, it must be set to `PRIMARY KEY (id)` - see the MySQL docs - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: you're right, as someone mentioned, the id was missing. Works well now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> Table 'db_1.info' doesn't exist

Means, that table `info` does not exist in db `db_1` so, make sure if that is the case.

Comment: @TudorManole table `info` in db `db_1` does not exist, because the `CREATE TABLE...` query was never ran in a `mysqli_query()`. It was just set as a php variable.

Comment: @Sean Well, it does not matter if it was created or not, because you are trying to get a data from non-existing table. which is `info`

Comment: I understood the problems everyone. Thanks for all the help, really appreciate it!